# file path problems with Zend Framework and fread()

Tags: php, file, zend-framework

I have a quick and hopefully simple question that I hope someone can help me with.  I have a application that I am working on and I allow users to upload files.  All files are loaded in to a directory with in the application folder of the project layout

/application

--/myuploadedfiles

/library

/public

However when I need to read them in using fread() I can't read the file as the path returned by the upload using Zend_File_Transfer_Http is

> ../application/myuploadedfiles/somefile.doc

Which when I try and read bombs out because fread can't seem to find it as I am getting this error

> fread(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource

What is the best way of getting the correct path to read the file so that I can process it??

I know that it is probably a simple bit of code but at the moment, I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Thanks.

Grant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try taking that relative path you get back from `Zend_File_Transfer` and passing it through the [`realpath()`](https://www.php.net/realpath) function before trying to read the file contents.

Comment: Thanks I knew it would be something simple.